# What is the minimum of 2 Weibull distributions with the same shape parameter

Tags: distributions, hazard, weibull-distribution, proportional-hazards, shape-parameter

If X and Y are two independent Weibull distributions with the same shape parameter, what distribution is the min(X, Y).
I am trying to find out the hazard ratio for the following case.
If I model Z=min(X, Y) with 2 independent Weibull distributions and C=min(A,B) with the 2 independent Weibull distributions, and all have the same shape parameter (say 2) (and hence satisfy the proportional hazards assumption), and the hazard ratio for X vs A is lambda and the hazard ratio for Y vs B is also lambda, what is the harzard ratio for Z vs C?

Comment: Welcome to CV! Since you’re new here, you may want to take our tour, which has information for new users.  Since this looks like homework (apologies if it's not), please add the [self-study] tag and read its wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing. If this is self-study rather than homework, let us know, and... it's still a good idea to show us what you've tried.

Comment: Noting that a Weibull r.v. is a power of an exponential r.v. (the shape parameter is related to the power), and that the minimum of two exponentials is relatively straightforward (noting that we don't change ordering by power transformation of a positive r.v.), this will have a pretty simple answer.

Comment: jbowman this is not a hw question. It is for some work I am doing.

Comment: Glen_b. It is easy for exponential distributions. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580279/how-to-prove-that-minimum-of-two-exponential-random-variables-is-another-exponen Can you elaborate a bit more for the Proof for min of 2 Weibulls?